# Conditionally replace neighbouring cells

Tags: matlab, for-loop, conditional-statements

Lets say I have a matrix `A`:

A =

```
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0
```

And I want to create a new matrix `B` of the same dimension where all `ones` and accompanying neighbours are replaced by the following matrix:

X =

```
 1     1     1
 1     2     1
 1     1     1
```

The `2` in matrix `X` should be placed 'on top' of the `1` values as to get:

B =

```
 1     2     1     0
 1     1     2     1
 0     0     1     2
 0     0     1     1
```

Values should be added up where elements overlap and matrix `X` should be 'cut off' in places where it extends the dimensions of matrix `A/B` The idea is to eventually replace `X` by a 2d gaussian distribution and matrix `A` will be large containing many more `ones`. So it's essential that the code is efficient and fast. This is the code i came up with:

```
 A = [0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 1;0 0 0 0]
 X = [1 1 1;1 2 1;1 1 1]
 B = zeros(4,4);
 t=1;

 indA = find(A==1);
 indX = find(X==2);
 all = find(X>0);
 [iall jall] = ind2sub(size(X),all);

 [ia ja] = ind2sub(size(A),indA)
 [ix jx] = ind2sub(size(X),indX)
 iv = ia-ix
 jv = ja-jx

 for t=1:numel(iv),
     ib = iall+iv(t);
     jb = jall+jv(t);

     ibjb = [ib(:), jb(:)]
     c1 = (ibjb(:,1)>4)|(ibjb(:,1)<1); c2 = (ibjb(:,2)>4)|(ibjb(:,1)<1);
     ibjb((c1|c2),:)=[]

     isel = ibjb(:,1)-iv(t)
     jsel = ibjb(:,2)-jv(t)

     B(ibjb(:,1), ibjb(:,2)) = B(ibjb(:,1), ibjb(:,2))+ X(isel, jsel)
     t=t+1;
 end
```

Is there a more efficient/faster way (minimizing the loops) to code this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a (2D) convolution. So use [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

```
B = conv2(A, X, 'same');
```